# How to keep lizards away from my patio?

Tags: pest-control

I live in San Diego and weather here is pretty accommodating to reptiles like lizards. Now, I have a house which has a patio facing bushes and I think lizards are making their way in through these passages. Now, long story short, I did try a lot of solutions like Egg-shells, to onion garlic paste and they do not seem to work.

The only thing that I found to be effective the the animal trap using pad glues. which works pretty fine but then we are responsible of getting rid of the lizard or release it somewhere. Of course, the same lizard may end up coming back to the patio as well. I was wondering if there is something that we can spray and keeps the lizards just away from the patio?

Comment: Are they Anole lizards ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactyloidae )? They are everywhere in Florida. I've never known anyone who found them offensive. Get a cat? My mother's cat would kill and eat them. And then puke. Maybe not a good solution :)

Comment: Don,t use glue traps on any animal.

Comment: remove their food source at your house and they will go someplace else

Comment: Oh, FFS!  This is just like folks here in New England who want a house in the country and then whine about snakes or bears or whatever wandering by.  San Diego is warm and is lizard country.  If you don't like it you shouldn't live there.  End of story.

Comment: just had to comment on this: " ... Egg-shells, to onion garlic paste and they do not seem to work..." Egg shells; basically sand. Lizards live on sand... Onion and garlic paste; reptiles do not taste (hence their ability to eat stinky bugs), so stinky stuff would have no effect. Not sure where that idea came from, but it never stood a chance of affecting lizard behavior...

Answer (score 10):

Chances are about 90% that these are Western Fence Lizards, commonly called "Blue Bellies" because of two large bright blue swatches on their undersides. **These lizards are eating your bugs, especially ticks. They typically eat their own weight in bugs every day so getting rid of them will result in a bug population explosion.**

Studies have shown Lyme disease is lower in areas where the lizards occur. When ticks carrying Lyme disease feed on these lizards' blood (which they commonly do, especially around their ears), a protein in the lizard's blood kills the bacterium in the tick that causes Lyme disease. The infection inside the ticks' gut is therefore cleared and the tick no longer carries Lyme disease.

Learn to like them. Think of them as your own personal pest control army...

Comment: Yeah, lizards are awesome. Wish we had more around our place. Between them and the frogs, the pests are naturally managed. Just wish they would target the mosquitos more. :)

Comment: Not enough of a meal I guess...